# Как парсить сайт, используя прокси, в Python?

Tags: python-3.x, proxy

Юзаю один из способов получить данные с сайта такой:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://www.example.com/")
```

ну или requests, если куки не нужны. 
Можно ли всё это же делать используя прокси какой-нибудь типа 111.111.111.111:8080?

Comment: вот примеры работы с [http](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431895/23044) и [SOCKS5](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/523568/23044) прокси, используя urrlib.

Comment: В Python 3 используется urllib3, не подскажите где можно почитать о различиях и вообще научиться грамотно его использовать? Если будет на русском, то вообще отлично. Задача использовать прокси и куки (в идеале иммулировать браузер), mechanize отпадает, т.к. он не дружит с Python 3.

Comment: urllib3 не связана с Python 3—это независимая библиотека, которая работает как на Питоне 2 так и 3. Примеры выше показаны для стандартной библиотеки (один для Питона 2, другой для Питона 3)—API с точностью до импортов осталось практически таким же (build_opener() и urlopen()).

Answer (score 1):

У браузера `mechanize` (работает в Python 2) есть метод для задания прокси - `set_proxies`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()

proxies = {
  "http": "111.111.111.111:8080",
  "ftp": "proxy.example.com",
}
br.set_proxies(proxies)

br.open("http://www.example.com/")
```

В доках [есть полезные примеры](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/).

---

Через прокси, так же можно ходить и в `requests` (работает в Python 2 и 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests

proxies = {
  'http': '10.10.1.10:3128',
  'https': '10.10.1.10:1080',
}

requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)
```

Поддерживаются и SOCKS прокси. Подробности в [документации](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies).

---

И да, `requests` конечно же [умеет работать и с `cookie`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies). RTFM, как говорится!

Comment: К сожалению не удалось подружить mechanize с Python 3.

Comment: @Олег значит, заводите дружбу с `requests` - библиотека на все случаи жизни. Обновил ответ.

Comment: @zed: чтобы обозначить на каких версиях ваши примеры можно запустить и то что они могут работать как отдельно стоящие скрипты, [вы можете добавить shebang (`#!` строку)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31954823/4279). К примеру, `#!/usr/bin/env python2` для первого примера и `#!/usr/bin/env python` для второго (второй пример как на Питоне 2 так и 3 должен работать).

Comment: не могли бы вы пояснить, что вложили в понятие "обозначить" ибо в данном контексте это можно трактовать по разному?

Comment: @jfs Спасибо, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Олег в данном случае «обозначить» это перевод "to indicate." Просто подсказка для читателя что код как скрипт можно запустить и есть ли ограничения на версию Питона.